# How to add WINAPI code to MFC?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, win32gui

I had to combine MFC and WinAPI: add WINAPI code to MFC,
the following are MFC and WinAPI code:

**MFC code**

```
void MyMFCView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) 
{
......
}
```

**WinAPI code**

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Win32Fun(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
......
}
```

Can I do like this:

```
void MyMFCView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) 
{
    Win32Fun(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: There is not technical barrier that prevents C++ (MFC) code from calling into C (WinAPI) code. Since the signature of your WinAPI code very much looks like it is part of message handling, however, things are different. MFC implements a message handling framework, and if you sidestep it, all sorts of breakage will ensue.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There's no magic involved. The fact that the base class of your class is taken from the MFC library doesn't change the fact that it's C++. The WINAPI is C code, and C++ can call C.